# Azure App Service scale out more than 100 instances?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I read here that you can max scale out to 30 or 100 instance depending on pricing tier.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up

But what if you need more?

100 doesn't sound that much if you website becomes big as Wikipedia and needs to scale and load balance throughout the world.

Is it really true that its only 100 or am i missing a point or something?

Comment: Check the [app limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits), it says the max instances is `100 dedicated`, there is a description about this. `More are allowed upon request.`

Answer (score 2):

As George mentioned in the comment, the maximum number of [Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits) for the Isolated plan is up to 100.

[image]

However, to answer your original question, there are various ways to architecture your application based on the needs, in case of large applications you can go for either containerization/Batch or microservice architecture. Here is a **[`diagram`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree)** that would help you to understand more,